# openvas-scanner is not found error for gvm check setup, how to solve it?

Tags: openvas

Step 1: Checking OpenVAS (Scanner)...
ERROR: No OpenVAS Scanner found.
FIX: Please install OpenVAS Scanner.

ERROR: Your GVM-21.4.3 installation is not yet complete!

Please follow the instructions marked with FIX above and run this
script again.

Comment: I compiled the steps that work for installing openvas here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAfxKYIIlvE

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue when i installed openvas on ubuntu 22.04, you can actually fix this yourself. The issue has to do with shared libraries, where openvas is searching for those shared library they are not located there.

1. Find out which shared libraries are missing

   ```
   $ ldd /usr/sbin/openvas
   # Look for libraries with "Not found"
   ```
2. After identifying those library marked as not found locate where those shared libraries are

   ```
   $ sudo find / -name libopenvas_nasl.so
   $
   # Replace libopenvas_nasl.so with the library you want to know it's path
   ```
3. After locating the page of that shared library, create a link to where openvas is searching for those libraries

   ```
   $ ln -s /usr/lib64/libopenvas_nasl.so.21 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
   ```
4. After try running that failed command again, on my side it worked. or try

   ```
   $ openvas -s 
   $
   $ # It should work
   ```

Comment: I did this and it got me a bit further, but then it turned out the gsad daemon was missing (what's in a name, it ends with "sad") and I could not find any repo package to install it from. I tried also Ubuntu 20.04 but that didn't help.
I then switched to Kali Linux. There, the Greenbone/OpenVAS packages just work. And there are plenty of guides to help you install and configure them.

Answer (score 1):

In the configuration file location `/etc/ld/so.conf.d/' of` dynamic linker run-time bindings' there must be a conf-file containing a reference pointing to the location of the libraries in question.

For example:
If the 'missed' libraries are located at `/usr/lib64',  create a new config file` /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-openvas.conf'
and add  the following one liner
/usr/lib64

Save the file.

Last step is, run ldconfig -v and do verify if the cache has been rebuilt. Now check if `openvas' does run without moaning about the missing library.

Answer (score 0):

to add to wangolo joel comment; you may need to do the same thing for libopenvas_misc.so.21 as libopenvas_nasl.so.21

Error message:
`error while loading shared libraries: libopenvas_misc.so.21: cannot open shared object file:

Fix:
`ln -s /usr/lib64/libopenvas_misc.so.21 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenvas_misc.so.21`

Comment: Referring to another answer from someone else is OK only if that info is in your answer. As written your answer is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libopenvas_misc.so.21 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenvas_misc.so.21
```

and

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libopenvas_nasl.so.21 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenvas_nasl.so.21
```

then the ospd service won't start for permission reason

```
sudo chown -R _gvm:_gvm /run/ospd
sudo chmod 666 /var/log/gvm/openvas.log
```

after using this fix run again `gvm-check-setup` and everything should be ok. This is for the version 21.4.